# ubuntu unpacking failed when trying to install

Tags: kubuntu

Got an error "ubuntu unpacking failed" when trying to install xubuntu-16.04.6-desktop-amd64.iso via USB.

Anyone can help?

Thanks.

Comment: FYI: Xubuntu 16.04 LTS being a flavor of Ubuntu had only 3 years of supported life (https://xubuntu.org/release/16-04/ http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/03/01/ubuntu-16-04-6-lts-released/) which ended 2019-April. Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Server (no desktop) or Desktop (Unity 7) have 5 years of supported life and are still supported. Refer release notes, or use `ubuntu-support-status` on your own system to confirm this is the case. I suggest you move to a supported release of Xubuntu for security reasons, unless you're off-line or are aware of risks.

Comment: Even if you're willing to use a *only-partially* supported system, all support ends in 2021-April anyway, so why not start with a fully supported release?  Why also when you mention Xubuntu as your ISO, have you tagged Kubuntu?   *As to your issue; did you verify your ISO was flawless (ie. checksum check?), then validate your write to install media?  If was a VM did you provide sufficient RAM for it to run...*